# How to get user avatar in specific guild from discord.py

Tags: discord.py

I am developing a custom bot using the discord.py library (version 2). I want to retrieve the avatar of a member within a specific guild, but the member.avatar attribute only returns the user avatar instead of the guild-specific avatar.

Here's an example of the code I've tried:

```
member = guild.get_member(user_id)
avatar = member.avatar
```

In the above code, guild represents the specific guild I am interested in, and user_id is the ID of the member whose avatar I want to retrieve.

I have also attempted using other attributes such as member.avatar_url, but it also returns the user's global avatar instead of the guild-specific avatar.

Is there a way to obtain the member's avatar specific to a particular guild using discord.py? If so, how can I achieve this?

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use the [`guild_avatar`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Member.guild_avatar) attribute:

```py
member = guild.get_member(user_id)
avatar = member.guild_avatar
```